# React Native WebView scroll behaviour doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, scroll, webview

I have a native app that uses React Native [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) to wrap a web page.

```
      <WebView
        ref={webview => (this.webview = webview)}
        source={{
          uri: `http://localhost:8000`
        }}
      />
```

In this example, the page is simply pointing to an instance of localhost that has the following code, which increments a number when the user scrolls:

```js
var i = 0;
var $el = document.getElementById('counter')

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  i += 1;
  $el.innerText = i
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 2000px; background: linear-gradient(dodgerblue, yellowgreen)">
<div id="type"></div>
<div id="counter" style="position: fixed">0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The scroll behaviour inside a React Native `WebView` behaves in a way that is different to the browser. It waits for the scroll to finish before firing a `scroll` event.

Here is a comparison of the behaviour; in the browser, the scroll event fires while the scroll is in progress, as wanted and as expected:

[image: scroll-behaviour--browser]

In a React Native project in iOS 11, the scroll event fires after the scroll has finished:

[image: scroll-behaviour--simulator]

This behaviour is used presumably for performance reasons but it's all but killing the intended behaviour of my app.

Is there another work around I haven't thought of?

**How can I ensure the scroll event behaves in the same way as the browser inside my React Native app?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the below information on [MDN scroll event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll). I think issue is not related to react-native.

> ### Browser compatibility
>
> **iOS UIWebView**
>
> In iOS UIWebViews, `scroll` events are not fired while scrolling is taking place; they are only fired after the
>   scrolling has completed. [See Bootstrap issue #16202](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16202). Safari and
>   WKWebViews are not affected by this bug.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by using [WKWebView](https://github.com/CRAlpha/react-native-wkwebview) instead of the React Native WebView.

Comment: No need to for this library as to use WKWebView you can simply put one flag for existing react native webview https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#usewebkit